# Java very simple regular expression puzzle

Tags: java, regex

I understand Java regular expressions can be accessed from the `String`'s `matches` convenience method, or going the long route and making a `Pattern`, etc. So, the following code should really print 2 "Yes!" lines to the output. It prints "Yes!" line and "no" line. What am I missing?

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TestRegex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pattern = "html";
    String input   = "somehtml.txt";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Yes!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("no");
    }

    if(input.matches(pattern)) {
        System.out.println("Yes!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("no");
    }

}

}
```

Output:

```
Yes!
no
```

Java version 1.6 on Win7 64-bit.

C:\Users\Michael Smith>java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`matches()` checks for the whole string matching the regular expression. `find()` only looks for a match somewhere in the string.

Answer (score 2):

[String#Matches](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method checks the pattern against the entire input text. This is the reason  your code prints `no` second time. [Matcher#Find](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) scans input to find next matching 
subsequence in the input.